# How to create intrumentation for add contraint on number of queries executed in single API call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql

I'm using spring-graphql 1.0.1 version, looking to add custom instrumentation to deny user to query if he tries to execute queries > n. It will help to protect graphql server by serving limited number of queries per request.

To add the maxQueryComplexity and maxQueryDepth instrumentation are available, which I have configured as follows. Is there any way to create a custom instrumentation to for maxQueries

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.graphql.instrumentation", name = "max-query-complexity")
public MaxQueryComplexityInstrumentation maxQueryComplexityInstrumentation(@Value("${spring.graphql.instrumentation.max-query-complexity}") int maxComplexity) {
    return new MaxQueryComplexityInstrumentation(maxComplexity);
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.graphql.instrumentation", name = "max-query-depth")
public MaxQueryDepthInstrumentation maxQueryDepthInstrumentation(@Value("${spring.graphql.instrumentation.max-query-depth}") int maxDepth) {
    return new MaxQueryDepthInstrumentation(maxDepth);
}
```

Comment: I found a solution to by writing the custom instrumentation by extending SimpleInstrumentation from graphql-java

```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to by writing the custom instrumentation by extending SimpleInstrumentation from graphql-java

Instrumentation class as below

```
public class MaxQueryCountInstrumentation extends SimpleInstrumentation {

   private int maxQueryCount;
   public MaxQueryCountInstrumentation(int maxqueryCount) {
        this.maxQueryCount=maxqueryCount;
    }


    @Override
    public InstrumentationContext<ExecutionResult> beginExecuteOperation(InstrumentationExecuteOperationParameters parameters) {
        int size = ((OperationDefinition) parameters.getExecutionContext().getDocument().getDefinitions().get(0)).getSelectionSet().getSelections().size();
        if (maxQueryCount < size)
            throw new AbortExecutionException("Maximum query count exceeded " + size + " > " + maxQueryCount);
        return SimpleInstrumentationContext.noOp();
    }

}
```

Config as below:

```
@Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.graphql.instrumentation", name = "max-query-count")
    public MaxQueryCountInstrumentation maxQueryCountComplexity(@Value("${spring.graphql.instrumentation.max-query-count}") int maxqueryCount) {
        return new MaxQueryCountInstrumentation(maxqueryCount);
    }
```